# Multi-project Trac Install for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, trac, ubuntu-14.04

I'm going to preface this wall of text by saying that there are a few similar questions about, none of which deal with my particular use-case...  I'm trying to get a Trac running under Ubuntu 14.04, specifically with support for multiple projects (Most guides don't seem to cover that one).  I'd like to eventually move it to a proper VirtualHost with SSL support, but that's beyond the scope of this for now.  [Feel free to pitch in on that too though, if you like.]

Following [this](http://robertbasic.com/blog/trac-on-ubuntu) old-ish guide, I've gotten the server going to the point where I can get to the Trac pages, but...

- Even with a user added as TRAC-ADMIN, I get a  "Authentication information not available. Please refer to the installation documentation." error when I go to the login page.
- Apache is not enforcing the .htpasswd login requirement for that folder.

Snippet of apache2.conf, taken from the very end (rest is default Ubuntu 14.04 config):

```
WSGIScriptAlias /trac /var/trac/apache/trac.wsgi

<Directory /var/trac/apache>
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Require all granted

    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Location "/trac/login">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "trac"
    AuthUserFile /var/trac/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: Do you know it's possible to have multiple projects in one Trac environment? Use SimpleMultiProjectPlugin for this.

Comment: I'm going to give that plugin a shot and see if it'll allow me to do what I need!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as though this will be OBE in the 1.1 Trac release, and as such I'm going to wait for a proper solution.  We'll get by with one install and a project field and port over when the new release is available.